# Bootstrap Carousel image stack

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to learn how to use a bootstrap carousel. My problem is that my two images stack on each other. I've been looking thru the code 100 times but can't figure out what's wrong.

```
 <div id="filmSnurraID" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#filmSnurraID" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#filmSnurraID" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./frukt2.jpg" alt="Ett plan">
                <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>Ett plan</h3></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./frukt1.jpg" alt="Ett annat plan">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#filmSnurraID" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#filmSnurraID" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a JSFiddle, Plunker, Codepen or code snippet (with also Bootstrap enclosed), so the answer is easier to give. _Probably_ it has something to do with your positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the problem here?**

I presume, you have not correctly imported Bootstrap CSS in your code.
As you see this [ERROR CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/eeemXJ?editors=1010), where I have removed Bootstrap CDN.

Hence please follow the below steps.

---

All you need is,stack your css/script files in correct order

**CSS Imports**

1. Bootstrap CSS CDN/File import

**JS Imports**

2. Jquery CDN
3. Bootstrap JS CDN (As this depends on Jquery, hence Jquery needs to be loaded first)

---

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="filmSnurraID" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#filmSnurraID" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#filmSnurraID" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="Ett plan">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Ett plan</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.aussiespecialist.com/content/asp/en_sg/sales-resources/image-and-video-galleries/jcr:content/mainParsys/hero/image.adapt.1663.medium.jpg" alt="Ett annat plan">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#filmSnurraID" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#filmSnurraID" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: No worries, please upvote the answer as well. Thanks and good luck.